# Calendar view CSS

Tags: views, theming, datetime

I have a rather silly CSS issue with my multi- and single-day calendar events. The multi-day calendar events display fine, however there appears to be white space between the border and yellow background for single-day calendar events (see image.)

[image]

Here's **(some)** of my override CSS code which I think is responsible. I'd very much appreciate some guidance on how to get rid of the white space!

```
.calendar-calendar .item {
  color:#333333;
  border:1px solid #C2C2C2;
  border-radius:10px;
}
```

I've tried adding `padding: 0;` to no avail.

Comment: P.S. the right brace } is in my CSS... don't be alarmed.

Comment: is there a height begin set some where.

Comment: Try inspecting your element to see where the problem is. Firebug or Chrome Inspector would work.

Answer (score 0):

The inspector definitely helped, Scott...I'm nearly there now:

```
.calendar-calendar .month-view .full .inner .monthview, .calendar-calendar .week-view .full .inner .weekview, .calendar-calendar .day-view .full .inner .dayview {
  border-radius:10px;
}
.calendar-calendar .month-view .full td.single-day div.monthview, .calendar-calendar .week-view .full td.single-day div.weekview, .calendar-calendar .day-view .full td.single-day div.dayview {
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
.calendar-calendar .month-view .full .inner .monthview, .calendar-calendar .week-view .full .inner .weekview, .calendar-calendar .day-view .full .inner .dayview {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Thanks for everyone's help.